# mysqli Table Joining

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I’m using Ajax to retrieve information from my database. I have no trouble sending to server PHP and getting information back using simple SQL queries. I came across a section that I needed to pull from 2 tables (Same Database) Both in common are column `PO`.  Attached is a picture of an example. 
I have been trying to pull everything from one table that meets my condition like Month of, year of and Store. I have been able to JOIN them but not successfully.   Closest I ever got is it checks both tables and only returns the data that have matching PO and not the rest of Table 1. 
I like for it to retrieve all rows in table one that meet the conditions and if there is a matching PO in table2 join it else continue to retrieve from table1. 
Please any help would be grateful

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Thank you

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM weekly_report LEFT JOIN tracker ON weekly_report.PO = tracker.POt WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(`Need By Date (Date)`, '%m-%d-%Y')) = '$month' AND YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(`Need By Date (Date)`, '%m-%d-%Y')) = '$year' AND weekly_report.`Ship To Location (Location ID)` LIKE '%$store%' GROUP BY (weekly_report.PO)";
```